# Javascript onload in sugarcrm

Tags: javascript, onload, sugarcrm

I am currently customizing a SugarCRM instance. In one module I have created a few custom fields and a drop down menu. Based on the selection of the drop down menu I want to show or hide some of my fields. This works fine. My question is about the initial load of the page: In that case, all possible fields are displayed - not only the ones that should be displayed based on the default selection in the drop down menu.

My first instinct was to register the onload event and just hide whatever I don't need to see when the page is loaded. But I couldn't find anywhere to place it as I don't want to change /modules/... directly. I'd like to restrict my changes to /custom/modules...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Here few ways to control dropdown visibility:

1. There is admin when you edit field there is formula and visibility functionality you can also try this.
2. Create custom edit view and add javascript code in display function of view.
   custom/modules//views/view..php

.php');

    class View extends View {
        function View() {
            parent::View();
        }

        function display() {
          echo '';

          parent::display();
        }

    }
?>

3. Custom Javascript can be added to editviewdefs.php

   ```
       'templateMeta' =>
       array (
      includes' => array (
                  1 =>array ('file' => 'custom/modules/<ModuleName>/js/custom.js',),
       ),
   ),
   ```